# unknown url type: '//drive.google.com/drive/folders/11XfAPOgFv7qJbdUdPpHKy8pt6aItGvyg'

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I am trying to use Haar cascade classifier for object detection.I have copied a code for haar cascade algorithm but its not working.It's giving error as 
unknown url type: '//drive.google.com/drive/folders/11XfAPOgFv7qJbdUdPpHKy8pt6aItGvyg'
even though this link is working.

import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import cv2

import os

def store_raw_images():
    neg_images_link = '//drive.google.com/drive/folders/11XfAPOgFv7qJbdUdPpHKy8pt6aItGvyg'
    neg_image_urls = urllib.request.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()
    pic_num = 1

```
if not os.path.exists('neg'):
    os.makedirs('neg')

for i in neg_image_urls.split('\n'):
    try:
        print(i)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(i, "neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg")
        img = cv2.imread("neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        # should be larger than samples / pos pic (so we can place our image on it)
        resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
        cv2.imwrite("neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg",resized_image)
        pic_num += 1

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

store_raw_images()

I am expecting output as set of negative images for creating dataset module for object detection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing "https:" at the start of the url is the causing the specific error.
Furthermore, you cannot just load a drive folder when it is not shared (you should use the drive link) and event then it is not optimal, you have to parse the html response and it may not even work.
I strongly suggest you to use a normal HTTP server or the Google Drive python API.